# Bulk delete elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

i am using elastic search 2.2.

here is the count of documents

curl 'xxxxxxxxx:9200/_cat/indices?v'

```
yellow open   app                 5   1   28019178         5073     11.4gb         11.4gb
```

In the "app" index we have two types of document.

1. "log"
2. "syslog"

Now i want to delete all the documents under type "syslog".

Hence, i tried using the following command

```
 curl -XDELETE "http://xxxxxx:9200/app/syslog"
```

But am getting the following error

```
No handler found for uri [/app/syslog]
```

i have installed delete-by-query plugin as well. Is there any way i can do a bulk delete operation ?

For now , i am deleting records by fetching the id.

```
curl -XDELETE "http://xxxxxx:9200/app/syslog/A121312"
```

it took around 5 mins for me to delete 10000 records. i have more than 1000000 docs which needs to be deleted. please help.

[EDIT -1]

i ran the below query to delete syslog type docs

```
curl -XDELETE 'http://xxxxxx:9200/app/syslog/_query' -d'
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match_all": {}
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}'
```

And result is below

```
{"found":false,"_index":"app","_type":"syslog","_id":"_query","_version":1,"_shards":{"total":2,"successful":1,"failed":0}}
```

i used to query to get this message from index

```
 {
      "_index" : "app",
      "_type" : "syslog",
      "_id" : "AVckPMQnKYIebrQhF556",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "_source" : {
        "message" : "some test message",
        "@version" : "1",
        "@timestamp" : "2016-09-13T15:49:04.562Z",
        "type" : "syslog",
        "host" : "1.2.3.4",
        "priority" : 0,
        "severity" : 0,
        "facility" : 0,
        "facility_label" : "kernel",
        "severity_label" : "Emergency"
}
```

[EDIT 2]

Delete by query listed as plugin

```
sudo /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/plugin list
Installed plugins in /usr/share/elasticsearch/plugins/node1:
    - delete-by-query
```

Comment: if the document number is large, you should rather create a new index and reindex the documents you want to keep

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem, after filling elasticsearch with 77 millions of unwanted documents in last couple of days. Setting timeout in query is your friend. As mentioned [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/docs-delete.html#delete-timeout). Curl has parameter to increase too (-m 3600)

```
curl --request DELETE \
  --url 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/nadhled/tree/_query?timeout=60m' \
  --header 'content-type: application/json' \
  -m 3600 \
  --data '{"query":{
            "filtered":{
              "filter":{
                "range":{
                  "timestamp":{
                    "lt":1564826247
                   },
                  "timestamp":{
                    "gt":1564527660
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }'
```

I know this is not your bulk delete, but I've found this page during my research so I post it here. Hope it helps you too.

Answer (score 1):

In latest Elasticsearch(5.2), you could use ***_delete_by_query***

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/index/type/_delete_by_query" -d'
{
    "query":{
        "match_all":{}
    }
}'
```

> The delete-by-query API is new and should still be considered
>   experimental. The API may change in ways that are not backwards
>   compatible

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html

Answer (score 1):

**ES 8.11, 2024-01**

I don't know what the situation was in 2016, but maybe you could consider doing a [bulk delete](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html#bulk-api-request-body). What is being described in the other answers at this writing is a `_delete_by_query`, not a bulk delete. Study that page to understand how bulk operations work.

The downside of this is that it might be quite complicated to determine the `_id`s of all the LuceneDocuments (index documents) you need to delete. Typically you might have to run a _search query to find these `_id`s on the basis of your query. You must have these `_id`s to do a bulk delete.

Someone might say: "ah, but if you have to run a _search and then sort out the _ids and then do a bulk delete, surely that's going to be terribly, terribly slow". I'm not at all sure that that's right: I believe a `_delete_by_query` turns out to be a very lengthy operation, as the OP has found, when it is meant to apply it to a large number of records, ... whereas a _search might return results very quickly indeed. Parsing the results, and simultaneously creating the bulk delete string, could also be very quick<sup>1</sup>. And then ES executes these bulk operations incredibly fast.

You also have to make a bulk string conforming to the strict string format required. A bulk delete operation is simpler than a bulk index operation: it just looks like this:

```
{ "delete" : { "_id" : "234" } }
{ "delete" : { "_id" : "235" } }
{ "delete" : { "_id" : "236" } }
...
```

(This is the "application/x-ndjson" format you have to use).

---

<sup>1</sup> The choice of computer language might even come into play here, particularly if you can parallelise the parsing of the results from the _search. If I had to do this in a Python project I would seriously think about using a Rust module. But Python's limitations in terms of execution times shouldn't be exaggerated.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you should rather create a new index and reindex the documents you want to keep

But if you wanna use delete by query you should use this,

```
curl -XDELETE 'http://xxxxxx:9200/app/syslog/_query'

{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match_all": {}
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

but then you'll be left with mapping.

Comment: The delete query which you have given above will delete only A121312. i want to delete all docs under index "app" and type "syslog"

Comment: This isnt working.. let me edit my post now with query , result and sample message if that would help

Comment: i have given sample message as well. Am not sure why the query is resulting found=False eventhough we have syslog messages

Comment: have you installed delete by query plugin ?

Comment: it's taking `_query` as `_id`, check if delete by query plugin is installed

Comment: sudo /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/plugin list
Installed plugins in /usr/share/elasticsearch/plugins/node1:
    - delete-by-query

Its installed i believe

Comment: reason is version is 2.2, didn't support delete by query.